# I don't have database diagram in SQL Server 2012 , how can I get it turned on?

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-diagram

I don't have the database diagrams in my SQL Server 2012.

How can I turn it on, so that I will be able to extract a diagram of my database?

Answer (score 0):

In your object explorer you should have a Database Diagrams folder under the Database which you created. If you right click it you are able to click "New Database Diagram"

Are you missing this folder?